# Need write # under each tweet C#

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

Apologies in advance, English is not my first language.

I need to write under each tweet: `#....`.  I am using `Regex.IsMatch`, but console write all tweets.

```
var tweet = tweets[i].Text;
var CreatedDate = tweets[i].CreatedDate.ToString("F");
var TweetTime = DateTime.Parse(CreatedDate);
var age = DateTime.Now.Subtract(TweetTime);
Console.WriteLine(tweet);
Console.WriteLine($"с момента создания прошло {age} времени");
Console.WriteLine();

var pattern = @"#\D*";

foreach(var sharp in tweet)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(tweet, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        Console.WriteLine(sharp);
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, but `\D` matches everything that is NOT a number. Maybe if you use `@"#\d*"` it will work?

Comment: Can you please include an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: It's must look like "bla bla #someinfo bla bla" and under this text  "#someinfo" @maccettura

Comment: @emsimpson92 sec, ama tryin this

Comment: @emsimpson92 thx, but it's not work, "#someinfo" write in a column(wtf?)

Comment: @ТимурАлексеев do you want it under the tweet in the console?  Or do you want to modify each tweet object?

Comment: @maccettura under tweet in the console

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to implement, but i see why your not getting the hashtag to print.  Regex.IsMatch doesn't change the text it just evaluates it.  Try something like this.

```
var pattern = @"#\D*";

        foreach (var sharp in tweet)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(pattern, sharp);
            if (match.Success)
                Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(sharp, match.Value, "#" + match.Value, RegexOptions.Singleline));
            else
                Console.WriteLine(sharp);

        }
```

Comment: thx, but warning CS1503(Argument 1: cannot transform from "char" to "string" and CS0120

Answer (score 0):

Thank's all
Right anwsers is next:

```
 string pattern = @"\s*#(\w+)\s*";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(tweet);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                    Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
            }
```

Thanks for @M. Green